# cannot import name 'PdfFileReader'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

What does this error mean? Should I install something?

```
    from pdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
ImportError: cannot import name 'PdfFileReader'
```

I got it during compiling the following script:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__' and len(sys.argv) > 5 and sys.argv[1][-3:].upper() == 'PDF':
  original = sys.argv[1]
  target   = original[:-4] + '.cropped.pdf'
  left     = int(sys.argv[2])
  top      = int(sys.argv[3])
  right    = int(sys.argv[4])
  bottom   = int(sys.argv[5])

  from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
  pdf = PdfFileReader(file(original, 'rb'))
  out = PdfFileWriter()
  for page in pdf.pages:
    page.mediaBox.upperRight = (page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_x() - right, page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_y() - top)
    page.mediaBox.lowerLeft  = (page.mediaBox.getLowerLeft_x()  + left,  page.mediaBox.getLowerLeft_y()  + bottom)
    out.addPage(page)    
  ous = file(target, 'wb')
  out.write(ous)
  ous.close()

else:
  print ('EXAMPLE: pdfcrop.py original.pdf 20 30 20 40')
```

Comment: Your error doesn't match the code. Anyway, this is not a built-in library so yes - of course you need to install. But according to the error t looks like you have it installed...

Comment: By the way, `pyPdf` is not maintained anymore. You should check [`pyPdf2`](http://knowah.github.com/PyPDF2/)

Comment: Thank you. Thus, I should change pyPdf to pyPdf2? Then I installed it, it wrote that Requirement already satisfied but after running script, there is: No module named 'pyPdf2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**
The pyPdf library was outdated and didn't work as intended. The use of the PyPDF4 library fixed all issues created by the outdated library.

The error `ImportError: cannot import name 'PdfFileReader'`
means that there is an import error.

## Installing pip

[Pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) is the package installer for Python and is required to install Python Packages.

1. If you are using [Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html) onwards, then don't worry; pip comes pre-installed.
2. If you are using a version of Python 3 older than Python 3.4, then the official pip install instructions can be found [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#do-i-need-to-install-pip)

- Note: you can find out what version of Python you are running by typing `python --version` in the terminal

## Installing the [PyPDF4](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF4/) package

Once you have pip installed, you can now install the PyPDF4 package. This is as simple as typing `pip install pdf` into your terminal.

Once you've done this, you will successfully have the PyPDF4 package installed for Python.

## Other Sources of Error

However, it may well be that you have the package installed. Your error could also be that you are trying to import a function from the library that doesn't exist, or the library itself contains errors.

Comment: I have the package intalled. I have Python 3.6.9. The error still appears.

Comment: In the beginning, you say you run `from pdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter`, but in your code, it is `from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader`. Which one is it? Maybe you are using the wrong library, or maybe this is just a typo. You may also want to check that the function in the library is exactly called `PdfFileReader`.

Comment: In the code, there is `from pyPdf`, I do not know why the terminal is writing something different

Comment: It seems as if the error is coming from the library, not from your code. This may be because pyPdf is an outdated library. Try using a library such as PyPDF4 instead. PyPDF4 uses much the same documentation as pyPdf, but is well maintained and up to date.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works.